# Web forms keep bootstrap modal open and on next page after postback?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

Good morning all, I can't for the life of me find a working answer to this.  I'm looking to do exactly as the question states.

Just a little background, I'm working on an application that will have a "setup" process after first registering and logging in for the first time.  I'm doing this via a modal with Bootstrap.  There will be multiple steps where the user will be submitting data through an asp Button in order to update that database.

These steps are where I'm stuck as after the postback the page reloads and the modal reopens at the beginning of the getting started.

To help explain how I'm paging, I'm basically using a new div for each page with display: none until the get to that part of the setup.  Here is some of the code...

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="modalPageOne">
                ... content
                <asp:Button ID="btnOne" runat="server" OnClick="btnOne_Click" OnClientClick="NextPage();" Text="Submit">
            </div>
            <div class="modalPageTwo">
                ... content
                <asp:Button ID="btnTwo" runat="server" OnClick="btnTwo_Click" OnClientClick="NextPage();" Text="Submit">
            </div>
            <div class="modalPageThree">
                ... content
                <asp:Button ID="btnThree" runat="server" OnClick="btnThree_Click" OnClientClick="NextPage();" Text="Submit">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is some of the javascript

```
<script>
    var currentPage = 1;
    function NextPage() {
        if(currentPage == 1) {
            $(".modalPageOne").hide();
            $(".modalPageTwo").show();
            currentPage++;
        } else if
        ... finish else if for all pages
    }
</script>
```

That should be enough to show basically how I'm doing this setup process.  So basically when the asp Button is clicked I need to go to the next page.  If anyone has any ideas, that would be amazing!

Thanks,
Andy

Comment: Unless you need to do a postback for each page, I'd strongly recommend getting rid of the submit buttons for all except the last page.  Then you can simply attach an event handler to regular buttons that progress through the pages.  Then, just submit the data at the end of the process.

Comment: Hmm interesting, that's kind of been a thought in the back of my head, I guess I was just a little concerned that should there be an error when inserting the data, a user wouldn't be happy they need to go through the entire process again.  Thanks!

Comment: You could add page validation each time you call `NextPage()`, and not progress to the next page if there are any problems.  I have this exact thing in place on a checkout page and it works nicely.  People prefer it to the older version that did a page submit each time they clicked a button, as there's no waiting between pages.

Comment: Awesome, thanks much for your quick responses!  I think this is the way I'm going to go :) Thanks again!  Can a mark a comment as an accepted answer?

Comment: No, but since it's helped I'll put something together in the form of an answer.  Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having a different modal for each form, you could wrap an asp:multiview in a single modal div and modify the selected view on submit. Then you will always open the same modal with a different content.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend submitting all the data at the final page, and using the same modal for all previous pages.  Replace the submit buttons with regular buttons, and make them trigger the `NextPage()` code...

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="modalPageOne">
                ... content
                <button class="next-button">Next</button>
            </div>
            <div class="modalPageTwo">
                ... content
                <button class="next-button">Next</button>
            </div>
            <div class="modalPageThree">
                ... content
                <button class="next-button" onserverclick="btnSubmit_Click" runat="server">Next</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The `NextPage()` function would then need to submit the data...

```
<script>
    var currentPage = 1;
    function NextPage() {
        if(currentPage == 1) {
            // validate page contents here - return if invalid
            $(".modalPageOne").hide();
            $(".modalPageTwo").show();
            currentPage++;
        } else if {
            // etc..
        }
    }

    $(function() {
        $("button.next-button").on("click", function() {
            NextPage();
        });
    });
</script>
```

I also took the liberty of assigning click event handlers to the buttons using jQuery.  Inline event handlers have multiple downsides, and since you're already using jQuery you may as well take advantage of it.